# CGAL: How to extract facet locations from .off file

Tags: cgal

I am currently using the Shape Diameter Function on CGAL to extract the diameter of an .off file. The function outputs a segment id for each facet in the mesh, and I would like to find the location of each facet in a 3d space so I can pair each facet with its corresponding segment-id. Is this possible?

Thanks, 
Sharan

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_segmentation/group__PkgSurfaceSegmentation.html#ga8533ea7b1062ebbabe3bf23fed303f24), the parameter `SegmentPropertyMap` is exactly what you need.
If you look at [this example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_segmentation/Surface_mesh_segmentation_2segmentation_with_facet_ids_example_8cpp-example.html), it is done in the last 6 lines of code.

Comment: I am a bit new to the CGAL, so the documentation and the example were a bit unclear for me.

    In practice I constructed an isosurface in Matlab and exported it as an .off file, and computed the SDF from it. Now I would like to export the results to a disk so that each face would have a SDF value. Problem is that the SDF values are related to facets, but not to my original faces and vertices vectors. How do I get the correspondence and how could I write the values to disk?

Comment: The face and vertex order in the polyhedron is the same as in the OFF file.